# Javafx Formatting decimal number textfield

Tags: javafx, textfield

I have a problem with formatting a currency decimal number in `TextField`. I set the `TextFormatter` with a class `DecimalFormatter` that extend a `StringConverter` which converts a `BigDecimal` to `String` and vice-versa.
When I should change the value, if delete all the data and insert a new completed value it works, but if I have to add/change a part of value e.g. 13.00 in 13.10 the change is not applied and re-proposes the old value 13.00.
How can I solve it?
Thank you

```java
public class DecimalFormatter extends StringConverter<BigDecimal> {

    private NumberFormat numberFormat;

....

    @Override
    public String toString(BigDecimal value) {
        if ( value == null )
            value = new BigDecimal();
        return numberFormat.format(value.doubleValue());
    }

    @Override
    public BigDecimal fromString(String value) {
        return new BigDecimal(value);
    }

}

....

tfDecimal.setTextFormatter(new DecimalFormatter());
```

Comment: `TextField::setTextFormatter` accepts the `TextFormatter` argument rather than the `StringConverter`. The code shown should not even be compiled.

Comment: sorry! `tfDecimal.setTextFormatter( new TextFormatter(new DecimalFormatter()) );` 
I commented on the code badly

Comment: Leaving aside the fact that `BigDecimal` does not have a default constructor, the code works correctly (as long as the _numberFormat_ was created correctly).
The only problem I see is that there is no option to "delete" a value. In this case, any exception to the `StringConverter::fromString` method will result in the return of the last valid value (what you describe).

Comment: I think I made some confusion. Actually with the separator `.` it works and with the `,` that doesn't work, but adding the replacement function `value = value.replaceAll(",", ".");` in the `StringConverter::fromString` method now the value is accepted.

Answer (score 1):

My intention was to manage amounts with decimals separated by a comma in a textfield. I added a filter to allow only double amounts. The complete code:

```
public class DecimalFormatter extends StringConverter {

    private final NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.ITALY);

    public DecimalFormatter(int fractionsLenght) {
        numberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(fractionsLenght);
        numberFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(fractionsLenght);
    }

    public DecimalFormatter() {
        numberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        numberFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(BigDecimal value) {
        if ( value == null )
            value = new BigDecimal(0);
        return numberFormat.format(value.doubleValue());
    }

    @Override
    public Decimal fromString(String value) {
        value = value.replaceAll(",", ".");
        return new BigDecimal(value);
    }
} 
public class DecimalFilter implements UnaryOperator {

    private static final char DECIMAL_SEPARATOR = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance().getDecimalSeparator();

    private Pattern DIGIT_PATTERN;

    public DecimalFilter() {
        DIGIT_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("-?\\d*(\\" + DECIMAL_SEPARATOR  + "\\d{0,2})?");
    }

    public DecimalFilter(int fractionsLenght) {
        DIGIT_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("-?\\d*(\\" + DECIMAL_SEPARATOR  + "\\d{0," + fractionsLenght + "})?");
    }

    @Override
    public Change apply(TextFormatter.Change aT) {
        return DIGIT_PATTERN.matcher(aT.getText()).matches() ? aT : null;
    }
} 

tfDecimalValue.setTextFormatter(
    new TextFormatter(new DecimalFormatter(), new BigDecimal(0), new DecimalFilter()));
```